# zooming on svg with d3 in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, svg

I would pan/zoom on an svg.

I'm trying to use d3 as mentioned in [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/psogia/simplest-way-to-add-zoom-pan-on-d3-js)

Here's my code:

```
import { Component,AfterViewInit,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from "d3";
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.svg',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit,OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var svg = d3.select("svg")
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
       svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }))
    .append("g")
  }
}
```

Actually nothing is happening, scrolling on svg does not zoom

[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-resizing?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Is it really required to use `d3.js`? Zoom and pan can be done without `d3.js` with normal `css` and `Angular` mouse events.

Comment: not required to use d3, Can you give me more details ?

Comment: Are you using `<svg>` tag or as a source for `<img>`?

Comment: svg tag as in demo

Answer (score 2):

There is propper solution:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var zoomFn = d3.zoom().on('zoom', function() {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
});    
svg.call(zoomFn);
```

Comment: To be able to zoom in , should I add another code ? because i'm trying to scoll down to zoom but nothing is happening

Comment: @infodev, yes. Add my code and zoom will work as expected

Comment: @IhorYanovchyk How do we re-write this now that `d3.event` has been removed?

Answer (score 1):

For my case the solution from Ihor Yanovchyk was missing something. The svg was zooming in a weird way moving the whole svg out of the view. I had to add a selectAll('g') and change theri transform attribute instead.

What worked for my case:

```
const svg1 = select(this.svg1.nativeElement).call(zoom().on('zoom',function(){
    svg1.selectAll('g').attr("transform", event.transform)
}));
```

Comment: How do we re-write this now that `d3.event` has been removed?

Comment: @Muhy It could be written as: const svg1 = select(this.svg1.nativeElement).call(zoom().on('zoom',function handleZoom(event){
    svg1.selectAll('g').attr("transform", event.transform)
}));

Answer (score 0):

Giving example for `svg` as source on `<img>` tag

Import hammerjs inyour `app module`

```
<!-- app.module.ts -->
import 'hammerjs'
```

Following is the code for for img HTML.

```
<img [src]="imageSrc" alt="de-ethynizer" (pan)="onPan($event)" [ngStyle]="imageStyle()"
    (wheel)="onScroll($event)" style="cursor: grab">
```

Following is the component file

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
 scale: number;
  pan: any = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  constructor() {
    this.scale = 1;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

/* Method which adds style to the image */
  imageStyle() {
    return {
      transform: `translate(${this.pan['x']}px,${
        this.pan['y']
      }px) rotate(0deg) scale(${this.scale})`
    };
  }

  /* Method will be called on pan image */
  onPan(e) {
    this.pan = { x: e['deltaX'], y: e['deltaY'] };
  }

  /* Method will be called when user zooms image */
  onZoomP() {
    this.scale = this.scale + 0.1;
  }

  /* Method will be called when user zooms out image */
  onZoomM() {
// below you can check zoom out level from 0 to 1

    if (this.scale < 1) {
      return;
    } else {
      this.scale = this.scale - 0.1;
    }
  }

  /* Method will be called on mouse wheel scroll */
  onScroll(e) {
    if (e['deltaY'] < 0) {
      this.onZoomP();
    }
    if (e['deltaY'] > 0) {
      this.onZoomM();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Given example for `<img>`. You can use same mouse events and `css` with `[ngStyle]` on `<svg>` too. Or else you can pass `SVG` as `<img>` src and can use entire solution

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but it seems to only work if image is same size as container, else you can't pan more than the container's size. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nvm, managed to do it by storing original pan and edited separately.